# SQLite - How to use prepared statements?

Tags: sql, delphi, sqlite

I am trying out [Tim Anderson's SQLite3 Wrapper for Delphi](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/?page_id=659) and I am currently having problems using Prepared Statements. I can't use the [extended variant by SV](https://code.google.com/p/sv-utils/downloads/list) since I need to stay compatible with Delphi 6.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var
  sldb: TSQLiteDatabase;
  sltb: TSQLIteTable;
  q: TSQLiteQuery;
begin
  sldb := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(ADBFile);

  if not sldb.TableExists('vmd_nodes') then
  begin
    sldb.execsql('CREATE TABLE vmd_nodes (content_date BLOB, node_type_oid OID, content_type_pod OID, update_ts TIMESTAMP, create_ts TIMESTAMP, node_guid GUID PRIMARY KEY, parent_guid GUID);');
  end;

  // Try #1: hardcoded (works)
  sltb := slDb.GetTable('SELECT * FROM vmd_nodes WHERE node_guid = "asd"');
  try
    showmessage(inttostr(sltb.Count)); // Output: 1
  finally
    sltb.Free;
  end;

  // Try #2 (does not work)
  sltb := slDb.GetTable('SELECT * FROM vmd_nodes WHERE node_guid = ?', ['asd']); // ???
  try
    showmessage(inttostr(sltb.Count)); // Output: 0
  finally
    sltb.Free;
  end;

  // Try #3
  sldb.AddParamText('guid', 'asd'); // why is AddParamText member of sldb instead of q ???
  q := sldb.PrepareSQL('SELECT * FROM vmd_nodes WHERE node_guid = :guid');
  sldb.AddParamText('guid', 'asd'); // why is AddParamText member of sldb instead of q ???
  ShowMessage(q.SQL); // SELECT * FROM vmd_nodes WHERE node_guid = :guid => Nothing was replaced
  sltb := q; // How to get a TSQLIteTable out of the TSQLiteQuery ?
end;
```

Comment: I think you need to tell readers what problems you're having.

Comment: When I use GetTable() with the "Bindings" argument, the query fails with 0 results. If I hardcode the query, it works. My main "question" is how to use prepared statements. I can't find any information about this wrapper and all examples I could find don't use prepared statements - they just concatenate the SQLText string.

Comment: I _think_ you just first add the parameters using `sldb.AddParamText`, and then use `slDb.GetTable` with your parameterized SQL to get the result table right away.

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful idea. I could solve it now:   `sldb.AddParamText(':guid', 'asd'); sltb := slDb.GetTable('SELECT ... = :guid');` An additional problem was that `AddParamText` expected a colon at the first parameter. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the (somewhat strangely expressed) [docs](http://geoget.ararat.cz/help/SQLiteWrap.TSQLiteDatabase.html#GetTable), you *first* add the parameters, then use `GetTable` with your SQL to get the results, something like;

```
sldb.AddParamText(':guid', 'asd');
sltb := sldb.GetTable('SELECT * FROM vmd_nodes WHERE node_guid = :guid');
```